# Why is the following sentence correct?

Tags: comparative-constructions

The sentence I have is:

> A lifetime friend and relative, my neighbour was often interested in the same subjects that I.

I would 'correct it' by replacing the last part with *that I'm interested in*

however, the book that I have states that it is correct as it is. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** correct. It would be correct with *as* in place of *that*.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to rephrase the sentence to

> My neighbour, a lifetime friend and relative, was as interested in the same subjects as I am.